# Can't Get Animation to Work Properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a Jquery Animation that is supposed to take a div that covers the text box and bounce it up into the border when clicked. However i can't seem to get the animation to jump up after some remakes. Any Ideas?

Java Script

```
function moveup(title,text){
$(title).animate{
if (text).value==""){
                $(title).animate({
                  top: '-18px'}, '300');
                $('text').focus();
                }

                {
    $('.inputborder').css({
  border: 'solid 2px #49acc7'}, '300');
                }

                {
    $('.inputtitle').css({
  color: '#49acc7'}, '300');
                }
```

`}
}`

```
        function movedown(t){
            if (t.value==""){
                $('.inputtitle').animate({
              top: '0px'}, '300');
                            }

                            {
                $('.inputborder').css({
              border: 'solid 2px #bec3c8'}, '300');
                            }

                            {
                $('.inputtitle').css({
              color: '#bec3c8'}, '300');
                            }

        }
```

Inline Code

`<div id="custnumbertitle" class="inputtitle" style="z-index:2;position:absolute;width:300px;height:35px;text-align:left;left:23px;top:0px;vertical-align:middle;line-height:35px;" onclick="moveup('custnumbertitle,custnumber')"><span style="background-color:white;">  CUSTOMER NUMBER  </span> </div>`

`<Input Type="text" id="custnumber" onblur="movedown(this)" width="150px" style="z-index:1;position:relative;top:3px;right:0px;width:320px;height:30px;border-radius:20px;border: solid 0px #bec3c8;"><a href="#" class="tooltip">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like it could use a good amount of cleaning. First `(text).value=="")` needs to be `((text).value=="")` also there is a lot of brackets that seem to have no reason to be there. When you say you want a box to bounce that is covering a text input do you mean something like [this here](http://jsfiddle.net/S2gUd/)?

Comment: Very much so, i think that should work perfectly ^.^